# Getting array information from selected combobox item.

Tags: arrays, vb.net, combobox

I have a simple question. All I am needing to do is get the array information from the selected combo box item. I know about combobox.selectedindex but that's not my issue. I am needing to retrieve the Array information so once I select the students name it will show up their Original Grade and Curved letter grade. I have done the math already, I have everything down and done except for this. Here is my code.

```
      Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Dim Line_String As String

    Dim ArraySize_Integer As Integer = 0
    Dim Grades_StreamReader As IO.StreamReader
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim GradesFile_String As String = "Grades.txt" 'To hold the filename for opening
    Dim DialogResponse As DialogResult
    Dim x_Integer As Integer
    Dim Mean_Decimal As Double = 0
    Dim Total_Integer As Double = 0
    Dim sum As Double
    Dim stDev As Double
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim orgScore As Integer


    'Prompt to open the file

    'Set the initial folder to display
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory


    'Open the file
    With OpenFileDialog1
        'Begin in the current folder
        .InitialDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
        .FileName = "Grades.txt"
        .Title = "Select File or Directory for File"
        'Filter to show only .txt files
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
        'Display the open file dialog box
        DialogResponse = .ShowDialog()
    End With
    'Get the filename
    GradesFile_String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

    'Connect to the file
    Grades_StreamReader = IO.File.OpenText(GradesFile_String)
    'Read the file into a structure array until it runs out of data
    Do Until Grades_StreamReader.Peek = -1
        'Raed the data
        Line_String = Grades_StreamReader.ReadLine
        'Split the line into the fields
        StringArray_String = Line_String.Split(","c)
        'Dynamically size the array of structures
        ReDim Preserve StudentData_Person(ArraySize_Integer)
        'Assign the fields to the structure, trimming the space
        StudentData_Person(ArraySize_Integer).Name_String = StringArray_String(0).Trim
        StudentData_Person(ArraySize_Integer).Grade_String = StringArray_String(1).Trim
        'Increment for the next array element
        ArraySize_Integer += 1
        'Populate the combo box
        Students_ComboBox.Items.Add(StringArray_String(0))

    Loop
    'Close the file
    Grades_StreamReader.Close()

    'Count the scores
    'Convert from String to Integer
    Scores_TextBox.Text = ArraySize_Integer.ToString



    'Calculate the mean

    If StudentData_Person.Length > 0 Then
        For x_Integer = 0 To StudentData_Person.Length - 1
            Total_Integer += CInt(StudentData_Person(x_Integer).Grade_String)
        Next
        Mean_Decimal = Total_Integer / StudentData_Person.Length
    End If
    Mean_TextBox.Text = Mean_Decimal.ToString

    'Calculate the Standard Deviation

    If StudentData_Person.Length > 0 Then
        For x = 0 To StudentData_Person.Length - 1
            sum += ((CInt(StudentData_Person(x).Grade_String) - Mean_Decimal) ^ 2)
        Next
        stDev = Math.Round(Math.Sqrt(sum / (x - 1)), 2)

    End If
    stDev_TextBox.Text = stDev.ToString

    'Get information from ComboBox Selected Entry
    Students_ComboBox.SelectedIndex

    'Determine letter grade
    For y = 0 To StudentData_Person.Length
        If CInt(StudentData_Person(x).Grade_String) >= Mean_Decimal + (1.5 * stDev) Then
            CurvedGrade_TextBox.Text = "A"
        End If
        If (Mean_Decimal + (0.5 * stDev)) <= CInt(StudentData_Person(x).Grade_String) And CInt(StudentData_Person(x).Grade_String) < (Mean_Decimal + (1.5 * stDev)) Then
            CurvedGrade_TextBox.Text = "B"
        End If
        If (Mean_Decimal - (0.5 * stDev)) <= CInt(StudentData_Person(x).Grade_String) And CInt(StudentData_Person(x).Grade_String) < (Mean_Decimal + (1.5 * stDev)) Then
            CurvedGrade_TextBox.Text = "C"
        End If
        If (Mean_Decimal - (1.5 * stDev)) <= CInt(StudentData_Person(x).Grade_String) And CInt(StudentData_Person(x).Grade_String) < (Mean_Decimal + (1.5 * stDev)) Then
            CurvedGrade_TextBox.Text = "D"
        End If
        If CInt(StudentData_Person(x).Grade_String) < (Mean_Decimal - (1.5 * stDev)) Then
            CurvedGrade_TextBox.Text = "F"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

I also would then need to retrieve the information from this and calculate their score as given and push it back out to the text boxes which I can do.

Would I just do

```
    originalscore_textbox.text = StudentData_Person(SelectedIndex)
    curvedgrade_textbox.text = 'something like what's above this line
```

or something like that I know that's definitely wrong I am just showing y'all my concept of thinking. Any questions, please ask I will try my best to explain them. But this is literally all I need and I'm done with my program haha.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you posted how StudentData_Person is defined.

I suggest adding a new Curved_String field to StudentData_Person. And populate it when you have calculated the curved grade. Then you just do.

```
originalscore_textbox.text = StudentData_Person(SelectedIndex).Grade_String
curvedgrade_textbox.text = StudentData_Person(SelectedIndex).Curved_String
```